# Python regex capturing extra newline

Tags: python, regex

So, I've been cooking some regex, and it seems the regex library is capturing an extra new line when I use `((.|\s)*)` to capture multi-line text.. `[\S\s]*` works for some reason:

If you see below, the first regex produces an additional `\n` group, **why??**:

```
>>> s = """
... #pragma whatever
... #pr
... asdfsadf
... #pragma START-SomeThing-USERCODE
... this is the code
... this is more
... #pragma END-SomeThing-USERCODE
... asd
... asdf
... sadf
... sdaf
... """
>>> r = r"(#pragma START-(.*)-USERCODE\s*\n)((.|\s)*)(#pragma END-(.*)-USERCODE)"
>>> re.findall(r, s) [('#pragma START-SomeThing-USERCODE\n', 'SomeThing', 'this is the code\nthis is more\n', '\n', '#pragma END-SomeThing-USERCODE', 'SomeThing')]
>>> r = r"(#pragma START-(.*)-USERCODE\s*\n)([\S\s]*)(#pragma END-(.*)-USERCODE)"
>>> re.findall(r, s) [('#pragma START-SomeThing-USERCODE\n', 'SomeThing', 'this is the code\nthis is more\n', '#pragma END-SomeThing-USERCODE', 'SomeThing')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subregex

```
((.|\s)*)
```

matches `"this is the code\nthis is more\n"`. The outer parentheses capture this entire string.

The inner parentheses capture one character at a time (either any character besides newlines, or a space (including newline)). Since that group is repeated, the contents of the group are overwritten with each repetition. At the end of the match, the last character that was matched (`\n`) is kept in that group.

So, if you want to avoid that, either make the inner group non-capturing:

```
((?:.|\s)*)
```

or use the `([\s\S]*)` idiom for matching truly any character. It might be a good idea to use `([\s\S]*?)`, though, to make sure that the smallest possible number of characters are matched.

Comment: I always thought that the `(a|b)` actually meant *match a or b without capturing it* for some reason... It's getting too late to write for regex.

Answer (score -1):

This expression produces nested group

```
((.|\s)*)
```

Because you use nested braces. For single-character OR square braces is a proper choice; this syntax is suitable when you want to chose between 2 words

```
(treat|trick)
```

Comment: That (sub-)regex isn't even present in the OP's code, and neither this or the actual regex leads to a nested loop. Something like `((.|\s)*)*` would, but that's not the case here.